# View all one-star ratings for an app in the Google Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store

Just what the title says, how can I view all one-star ratings for an app in the Google Play Store? I cannot see how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best you can do is ordering the ratings (but the order is "surprisingly" descending...):

[image]

Comment: and to get that screen with that dropdown menu, first it shows http://i.imgur.com/N6ttqMg.png   then click the > in the far right, then it gives that screen shown in your answer.  Also, this is fine when there are a hundred of hundreds of reviews. but for hundreds of thousands of reviews it's not that feasible.

Comment: Yep, well done Google... It should be feasible to create some extensions to get all reviews and allow better filtering, but I'm not aware of any.

Comment: yeah and when somebody does write it, google will eventually change design again. I don't like what the world of computers has come to with GUIs.

Comment: I refined the question to a more global approach: [How do I view **all ratings** in Google Play Store?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54758/how-do-i-view-all-ratings-in-google-play-store)

Comment: Cool, sounds good, I wish there is some way to do it as it's pretty annoying... it's insane how bad UI is wrecking so many Google products.