# How can I list all the reviews I wrote in Google Play?

Tags: google-play-store

I wrote a few app reviews in Google Play. How can I list all the reviews I wrote in Google Play?

Comment: Related: [Where I can find my own Google+ Play reviews and ratings?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42126)

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't list all reviews though :/

Comment: Franck, does this help a little? http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/69392/8605